# Is it necessary to have an base OS for docker image?

Tags: docker

I am using Windows OS but to use docker I use CentOS VM over Oracle VM Virtualbox. I have seen a Dockerfile where centos is used as base image. First line of my Dockerfile is

```
FROM centos
```

If I check the Dockerfile of CentOS on Docker Hub then first line is

```
FROM scratch
```

scratch is used to build an explicitly empty image, especially for building images. Here I can understand that if I start traversing upward using "FROM " line then finally I will end up at "scratch" image. I can see that scratch can be used to create a minimal container.

Question: If I want to create some bigger applications using web server, database etc, then is it necessary to add a base OS image?

I have tried to search for mysql and tomcat and noticed that it finally uses a OS image.
My understanding of Container was that I can "just bundle the required software and my service" in the container. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, however "just bundle the required software and my service" may be cumbersome, especially if you also have some shell scripts that make further use of other support programs.

Using some base image that contains already all the necessary stuff is more convenient. You can share the same base image for several services and due to docker's layered images will have no overhead regarding disk space.